# Liberty Profile - JSP cannot resolve java.util.List

Tags: java, jsp, websphere-liberty

I am migrating a web application from Weblogic to Liberty Profile. I get the error "List cannot be resolved to a type " When I look at the java class that was generated from the JSP, its missing the import for java.util.List.

This seems to be an issue with collections without generics:

```
List alphabetIndexList = new ArrayList();
```

If I rewrite this to use generics, the error goes away:

`List<String> alphabetIndexList = new ArrayList<String>();`

However, there is also a problem when using List and initializing to a List:

`List<String> = getList(); (getList() return List<String>)`

So in this case it seems like the JSP precompiler is not adding the import for List, which may have something to do with the fact that its an interface.

There does not seem to be any setting in the element to control this behavior, perhaps its a bug?

THis worked with Weblogic and Tomcat.

Comment: JSP does not magically add imports. (Well it may depend on the version of the container)....You can add `<%@page import="java.util.*"%>`

Comment: Yep, Weblogic 10 was adding the imports.  Shame on me for not looking!

Answer (score 0):

The JSP spec says:

```
Packages java.lang.*, javax.servlet.*, javax.servlet.jsp.*, and
javax.servlet.http.* are imported implicitely by the JSP
container. No other packages may be part of this implicitely
imported list.
```

It was not very searchable :(